# 'Popen' object is unsubscriptable python 2.6

Tags: python, indexing, popen

I am new to Python and do not know how to manipulate vmstat unfortunately within a script. I have this code to get outputs of vmstat and after a lot of research i cannot figure out a way to assign it as a variable in runqueue1 = sample1[0]

```
    sample1 = Popen(['vmstat'] ,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = sample1.communicate()
    stdout.splitlines()[1]
    time.sleep(1)

    sample2 = Popen(['vmstat'] ,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = sample2.communicate()
    stdout.splitlines()[1]
    time.sleep(1)


    sample3 = Popen(['vmstat'] ,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = sample3.communicate()
    stdout.splitlines()[1]
    time.sleep(1)


    sample4 = Popen(['vmstat'] ,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = sample4.communicate()
    stdout.splitlines()[1]
    time.sleep(1)

    sample5 = Popen(['vmstat'] ,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = sample5.communicate()
    stdout.splitlines()[1]
    time.sleep(1)


    runqueue1 = sample1[0]
    runqueue2 = sample2[0]
    runqueue3 = sample3[0]
    runqueue4 = sample4[0]
    runqueue5 = sample5[0]
```

I run into this traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./cputool", line 106, in <module>
      cputool()
   File "./cputool", line 98, in cputool
      runqueue1 = sample1[0]
TypeError: 'Popen' object does not support indexing
```

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I could arrange this in a different way so it could be indexed/subscriptable? Any other way besides popen that I could get the values of vmstat, so they can assigned to a variable?

Comment: What values do you want?  e.g. what do you expect `sample1[0]` to return?  If you're looking for the standard output, you're already grabbing it further up:  `stdout, stderr = sample1.communicate()`

Comment: `mypipe = os.popen('find.exe . -type f ')    myvar = mypipe.readlines()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example, I hope it will help you to understand the basics:

```
import subprocess
import time

# delay between update in seconds for vmstats
interval = 2
# create the process
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['vmstat', str(interval)],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)

while True:
        try:
                # read operations are *blocking*
                # using readline() instead of read() or readlines()
                # we could start processing a line as soon it is received
                print 'output: %s' % proc.stdout.readline()
        except BaseException, error:
                proc.terminate()
                print 'terminated by %s' % error
```